# How Approximation in Equation is explained?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have obtained an equation which needs to be approximated in order to be true.  The equation is -

$ 2^{ \epsilon_1 }  -  2^{\frac{- \log(n!)}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon_1}{2} +1}=1$

$\epsilon_1$ is a decreasing function of $n$ and  $0< \epsilon_1 < 1/2$. We need to take floor of the left hand side, if we consider the equation as true.

To be precise-
$\epsilon_1= -\log(2^{n-s_2(n)}-2^{\frac{-1}{2}(( \log(n!)+ \epsilon_1)- 2( n- s_2(n)-1))})  +\log(2^{n-s_2(n)}) $

Where $s_{2}(n) $ is the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $n$.

But  I have not used any kind of approximation in the whole derivation.

How Can it be explained?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $c=2^{-\ln(n!)/2}\ll 1$, $x=2^{ϵ_1/2}>1$ so you get the quadratic equation
$$
x^2-2cx=1\iff(x-c)^2=1+c^2\\\iff x=c+\sqrt{1+c^2}
=1+\frac{2c}{\sqrt{1+c^2}+1-c}
$$
so essentially $x=1+c$ or
$$
ϵ_1=2\ln(1+2^{-\ln(n!)/2})\approx 2^{1-\ln(n!)/2}
$$
which is small and falling with $n$.

Comment: Left Hand Side of the equation has 2 terms with different rate of change (when we differentiate) . Are you saying that it is still possible to hold the equation for infinite number of n? if that is the case would you please give another example where this kind of phenomenon occurs ?  Note that I have defined $\epsilon_1$  in terms of $n$.

Comment: Note that $ϵ_1$ is a function of $n$. What I demonstrated is that you can combine both terms in a quadratic expression and then solve directly for $ϵ_1$ where the dominant term is given by my last expression. You can similarly derive exact bounds in the same range.